# show different link set on nav bar based on user logged in or not

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have the following blade template .It has a head nav bar which displays some links to a person who is not logged in(like 'register','log in' etc).But if a logged in user visit the page i want the nav bar to show different link set( like 'log out','create a blog' etc).How can i show different link set based on user log information?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    @include('partials._head')
  </head>
  <body>
    @include('partials._headnav') // it should show different link set
    <div class='container'>
        @yield('content')
    </div> 
    @include('partials._footer')
    @include('partials._javascript')

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the user is logged in and then display the nav for the logged user.

In the `_headnav.blade.php` file

```
@if(Auth::check())
 // your nav for logged in user
@else
// your nav for normal users
@endif
```

Comment: Yeah the same. Updated the answer

Comment: can i use 'auth'  class inside a blade template ?

Comment: Yes you can use auth()->check()

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like so:

```
@if (Auth::guest())
    <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
@else
    <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Logout</a></li>
```

Comment: problem is 'partials._headnav' has  boostrap nav bar .how can i change all the link based on user authentication.? can i use auth inside a blade template?

Comment: Yes, you can use Auth inside the blade template.